# Examples of Defective Distributions

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

I was reading about Stochastic Convergence and I came across a term called *Defective Distribution*.

Essentially what they refer to as a *{Defective Distribution* is a distribution that has all the properties of a *Cumulative Distribution* $F$, i.e.,

$1)$ $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$

$2)$  Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function it is also upwards continuous monotonic increasing function

**BUT**

the *Defective Distribution* does not have the property of the *Cumulative Distribution*

$3)$ $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x)=0$ and  $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)=1$

the *Defective Distribution* has

$3^{'})$ $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x)\geq0$ and  $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)<1$

---

I would like to ask if there is a know such distribution, i.e. a know *Defective Distribution* with the property $3^{'})$ ?

Comment: *All* such "distributions" are mixtures of (a) an ordinary distribution function, (b) a point mass at $-\infty,$ and (c) a point mass at $+\infty.$  This is an immediate consequence of $(3^\prime).$

Comment: @whuber By placing point masses at $+\infty,-\infty$ we avoiding taking the limit?

Comment: Actually, no.  We first have to extend the real line by adjoining points $\pm\infty$ at either end.  (There is a standard construction in topology--a form of "completion" at the "ends" of the space--to do this.) The masses you assign to these points do not help you evaluate limits concerning what happens on the usual real numbers.  Using the extended reals like this can be a helpful way to record information about (say) things that have less than a 100% chance of occurring.

Comment: Suppose you are betting, and you start with $\$10$, and at each bet can win $\$1$ with probability $\frac23$ and lose $\$1$ with probability $\frac13$.  Let $T$ be the time at which you run out of money.  What is $P(T\le t)$ for $t \in \mathbb N$?  For example $P(T\le 9)=0$ and $P(T\le 10)=3^{-10}$ Does the distribution of $T$ meet your definition of  *Defective Distribution* since there is a positive probability you never run out of money?

Comment: @Henry But is the distribution that you described, an increasing one?

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Yes.  $P(T \le t)$ is a weakly increasing function of $t$ (it jumps up for every even integer, starting at $t=10$).  It is not continuous (though it is càdlàg like all distributions) but the CDF of a binomial distribution is not continuous either.

Comment: @Henry Sorry I read it reversely. I think it does meet the definition, because it asks in the minus and plus infinity to be larger than zero and smaller than one, regardless if the distribution attains the zero or one value in between?

Comment: I wonder where you came across these distributions and what the point was behind introducing the concept.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus  I was reading about Empirical Processes, and suddenly they introduced this term. I was wondering, if I was the only one that ever came across to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, certainly.

For instance, the arctangent is monotonically increasing from $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\arctan x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. So something like

$$ F: x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-2\epsilon}{\pi}\arctan x $$

will satisfy $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x) = \epsilon$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x) = 1-\epsilon$ for any (small, but) positive $\epsilon$.

[image: plot]

R code:

```
xx <- seq(-10,10,by=.1)
epsilon <- 0.1
plot(xx,1/2+(1-2*epsilon)*atan(xx)/pi,
  type="l",las=1,ylim=c(0,1),xlab="x",ylab="F(x)")
abline(h=c(epsilon,1-epsilon),lty=2)
```

Comment: I think your formula might be a bit off--it looks like $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1-2\epsilon}{\pi}\arctan x$ would work. For anyone wondering, the main idea can be described using graph transformations: take the function $f(x) = \arctan x$, and multiply it by $1/\pi$ so its range is $(-1/2, 1/2)$. Then multiply it by some positive constant $k < 1$ so that the graph is slightly *more* vertically compressed, with a range of $(-k/2, k/2)$. Then add $1/2$ so the range is $((1-k)/2, (1+k)/2)$. In particular if $k = 1-2\epsilon$ then the range is $(\epsilon, 1-\epsilon)$.

Comment: @mathmandan: thanks for pointing that out, and of course you are totally right!

Comment: +1 We could also do this with any other function not? If $F(x)$ is the CDF of a non-defective distribution, then $G(x) = 0.5 + (1-\epsilon) (F(x)-0.5)$ is the CDF of a defective distribution.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: yes indeed. Plus, we can of course use $F\circ g(x)$ for any monotonically increasing function $g$.